# How to resize a float array?

Tags: python, arrays, image, resize, preprocessor

I would like to resize my array(contains float values) x_initial which is of shape (2382, 256, 256) to (2382, 256, 256,1).

When I use

```
x_initial = x_initial.resize(x_initial[0], x_initial[1], x_initial[2], 1)
```

I get an error

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index.
```

Is there any way to resize a float array?

Answer (score 0):

This is because `reshape()` expects integer index as input and you are giving float values as input. Try this out:-

```
x_initial = x_initial.resize(int(x_initial[0]), int(x_initial[1]), int(x_initial[2]), 1)
```